# Paint circle with Python in 3D view direction

Tags: python, add-on

I want to draw a circle into the 3d view in the direction of the current view rotation.

I have 2 vectors (center, mouse_pos), so I have two points in 3d space, so I have the radius - fine.

This is my code so far and the painted result:

[image]

```
segments = 32
mul = (1.0 / (segments - 1)) * (pi * 2)
self._vertices = [(sin(i * mul) + self._center[0], 
cos(i * mul) + self._center[1], 0) for i in range(segments)]
```

With this the circle is painted like I have a "top perspective". I also have a method to get the current view direction:

```
def get_view_direction(context):
    rv3d      = context.space_data.region_3d
    view_rot  = rv3d.view_rotation

    dir = view_rot @ mathutils.Vector((0,0,-1))
    return dir.normalized()
```

My question is now how to let the segments of the circle take the rotation of the view into account? Any ideas?

EDIT: First part solved:

```
rv3d      = context.space_data.region_3d
view_rot  = rv3d.view_rotation

segments = 32
mul = (1.0 / (segments - 1)) * (pi * 2)
points = [(sin(i * mul), cos(i * mul), 0) for i in range(segments)]

for point in points:
    vertex = view_rot @ mathutils.Vector(point)
    self._vertices.append(vertex)
```

What's left now is to take the radius and center into acount, and I want to move it along the view direction, but I already have a method for this:

```
def get_view_direction(context):
    rv3d      = context.space_data.region_3d
    view_rot  = rv3d.view_rotation

    dir = view_rot @ mathutils.Vector((0,0,-1))
    return dir.normalized()
```

So I guess I can add the direction multiplied by a scalar to each vector?

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys got it, sorry to again answer my own question:-)

```
rv3d      = context.space_data.region_3d
view_rot  = rv3d.view_rotation

segments = 32
mul = (1.0 / (segments - 1)) * (pi * 2)
points = [(sin(i * mul) * self._radius, cos(i * mul) * self._radius, 0) 
for i in range(segments)]

self._vertices = [view_rot @ mathutils.Vector(point) + 
                  self._center for point in points]
```